# wordpress wpml plugin - problem in language switching

Tags: php, apache, wordpress

I'm using the wamp package(Apache server) in my windows xp. After i followed the steps in the url [click here](http://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/cannot-activate-language-directories/) i'm not able to access the different language. The problem i'm facing in the .htaccess file. under the www folder i put all my wordpress files in the name wsa26-4. So the file structure will come like this wamp/www/wsa26-4/wordpress files. So i used the following code in my htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /wsa26-4/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But the problem i was facing is when i click the language switcher flag say german then it's redirecting to me the default wamp server page.(http://localhost/wsa26-4/de-->localhost index page).. How i  can fix this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to debug the .htaccess file like this.

What I always do is go to WordPress->Settings->Permalinks and save from there. Then, either WP can update the .htaccss file itself or it gives me the text to paste in.

In order for WPML to use languages in directories, 'fancy permalinks' need to work. You should test it first without WPML. Set a permalink structure such as 'Month / Day / Postname' and see that it works. For this, the server's rewrite module should work.

The .htaccess file needs to have the rewrite engine enabled (see the IfModule declaration). You should check if your local Apache server has this module enabled and if not, enable it.

Then, when this is OK, you can safely enable WPML's language directories option and it should run without any issues.

Comment: yes.. the problem was in the permalinks settings. Once i changed to the fancy one, everything works charm!! thanks for your info!